# How can I prevent a page with PHP content getting flagged in Security Review "Dangerous tags in content" check?

Tags: 7, security

I am using Drupal 7. I have a page that has a PHP body that I know does not have any dangerous tags. [According to the README.txt file](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/security_review/-/blob/7.x-1.x/README.txt?plain=1#L104) in Security Review I need to add this to the "security_review_known_risky_fields" system variable ? Can somebody provide an example on how to do this? I am not sure exactly what the entry in the variable table should look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In settings.php add the following:

```
$conf['security_review_known_risky_fields'] = implode(
  ',',
  array(
    'xxx',
    'yyy',
    'zzz'
  ),
);
```

...where 'xxx', 'yyy', and 'zzz' are the content hash strings shown for each problematic file in the Security Review report.

Comment: Does some of my answer need to be combined with this one?

Comment: Would be good if an example of this gets added to the module's README.

Answer (score 1):

The README says to create "a SHA-256 hash of the entity_id, entity_type, and field contents". It looks like you have to call `hash('sha256', $entity_id.$entity_type.$field_contents)` and save that in the `security_review_known_risky_fields` string variable, which can be done in settings.php. If there are multiple fields you want to allow, separate their respective hashes with commas.